# Compare five columns to five other columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, search, case

I want to compare five columns (x1-x5) to five other columns (y1-y5), to determine the extent to which they agree (in any order).

A score ranging from 0 to 5 is awarded, for the number of values (in x1-x5) that matched (in any of the five columns y1-y5).

I could write this out as a lengthy series of CASE WHEN statements, but is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

The values are all strings. Full text search is not available on the server.

The code below illustrates an example where n_found is what I am trying to create.

```
DROP TABLE mytable;
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id      INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,x1      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,x2      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,x3      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,x4      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,x5      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,y1      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,y2      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,y3      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,y4      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,y5      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,n_found INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,n_found) 
VALUES (1,'a','b','c','d','e','r','a','t','y','z',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,n_found)
VALUES (2,'e','a','b','d','c','m','o','a','b','z',2);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,n_found) 
VALUES (3,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',0);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,n_found) 
VALUES (4,'a','b','c','d','e','b','e','a','c','d',5);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,n_found) 
VALUES (5,'a','b','c','e','d','d','b','x','y','z',2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CROSS APPLY` and Table Value Constructor:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM (VALUES (x1),(x2),(x3),(x4),(x5)) AS t1(v)
             WHERE v IN (SELECT v
                         FROM (VALUES (y1),(y2),(y3),(y4),(y5)) AS t2(v))
            ) AS s(found);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/FLRN11031)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 n_found found  ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1  a  b  c  d  e  r  a  t  y  z  1       1      ║
║ 2  e  a  b  d  c  m  o  a  b  z  2       2      ║
║ 3  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  0       0      ║
║ 4  a  b  c  d  e  b  e  a  c  d  5       5      ║
║ 5  a  b  c  e  d  d  b  x  y  z  2       2      ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Note:

If you want to handle `NULLs` you could use `COALESCE` to exchange `NULL` with value that you are sure does not exists:

```
COALESCE(x1,'^')
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/TQSH91125)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

> *This seems to evaluate NULL as agreeing. Can you modify it so that NULL compared to NULL does not match?*

As I said before it is already working that way.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](http://rextester.com/EGS73656)**</kbd>

```
╔════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦══════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦══════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ x1 ║ x2 ║ x3 ║ x4 ║  x5  ║ y1 ║ y2 ║ y3 ║ y4 ║  y5  ║ n_found ║ found ║
╠════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬══════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬══════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║  6 ║ a  ║ a  ║ c  ║ e  ║ NULL ║ o  ║ y  ║ x  ║ y  ║ NULL ║       0 ║     0 ║
╚════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩══════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩══════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

**EDIT 2:**

To handle `NULL` you could also use `INTERSECT (ALL)` equivalent:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM (SELECT v,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY v ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS c
                   FROM (VALUES (x1),(x2),(x3),(x4),(x5)) AS t1(v)
                   INTERSECT
                   SELECT v,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY v ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
                   FROM (VALUES (y1),(y2),(y3),(y4),(y5)) AS t2(v)
                  ) AS s2
            ) AS s(found)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo4`](http://rextester.com/TVH7908)**</kbd>

Comment: This seems to evaluate NULL as agreeing. I see you mention COALESCE above, can you modify the code to illustrate how to use COALESCE in this example please? I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

not as pretty, but might perform better than the cross apply option.

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN x1 IN (y1, y2, y3, y4, y5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       + CASE WHEN x2 IN (y1, y2, y3, y4, y5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       + CASE WHEN x3 IN (y1, y2, y3, y4, y5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       + CASE WHEN x4 IN (y1, y2, y3, y4, y5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       + CASE WHEN x5 IN (y1, y2, y3, y4, y5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM myTable
```

<kbd>**[`Demo`](http://rextester.com/KCT25482)**</kbd>

Comment: And it won't handle `NULL` :)

Comment: @lad2025  it does not count nulls, which i thought was a requirement